# My Javascript code is safe to prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, xss

I have a website where I put two input parameters in the error page for convenience
The first parameter(code) is the error code
The second parameter(desc) is the error text

And both input parameters are displayed on the page in the  tag

So, to prevent XSS, I put the following code:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = urlParams.get('code');
const desc = urlParams.get('desc');
var el = document.getElementById("txt-code");
if (!(code.toLowerCase().includes("script") || 
      code.toLowerCase().includes("<") || 
      code.toLowerCase().includes(">")))
  el.innerHTML = code.toLowerCase().replace("script", "");
var deskarea = document.getElementById("desc-area");
if (desc == null || desc == '') {
  deskarea.style.display = "none";
} else {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("txt-desc");
  if (!(desc.toLowerCase().includes("script") || 
        desc.toLowerCase().includes("<") || 
        desc.toLowerCase().includes(">")))
    el1.innerHTML = desc.toLowerCase().replace("script", "");
}
```

As it is known, I filtered "<", ">", "script"(It doesn't matter if the letter is capital or small) so if a bad user enters a JavaScript code, the text will not be displayed on the page and will only be shown as empty string.

Is there a way to bypass my filter? if yes(tell me how can you bypass? and how to solve this bug?

I enter `<script>` `<div` ... but it's okay and prevent my site from XSS

Comment: The code does nothing to prevent `<img onerror="alert('XSS')" />` and even more generally trying to *blacklist* potential problems is always inferior to *whitelisting*. You'll just be playing whack-a-mole with every new thing that shows up and there is no reason to go that route.

Comment: The correct fix is to not interpret attacker-controllable parameters as HTML at all, by assigning to `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Where's the code that "filters" `<` or `>`? Isn't it strange to remove the raw text `script` from a string? What if I want to use it in my content?

Comment: <img onerror...> Will be empty because we use "<" or ">"

Comment: `.toLowerCase().replace("script", "");` doesn’t do much to `"<img onerror>"`. (Or to `"<scriptscript>"`, for that matter.)

Comment: But toLowerCase().includes("<") does match <img...>

Comment: One part of preventing XSS is also about creating code for which the reader knows what it is doing and that makes sense.  Let's assume for a moment the code would prevent XSS (I can't say that for sure, because there are various encoding tricks to prevent `<` detection).  But does your code make sense? Not really: Why do you have `code.toLowerCase().replace("script", "")` if you do not execute that part if `script` was found?  Why do you use `el.innerHTML` if HTML Tags are not allowed anyway (your tests for `<` and `>`)? If tags are not allowed then it should have been `el.textContent` .

Comment: Oh, I see. Your code is overcomplicated, but safe. You don’t need `replace` or to check for the word “script”, though; just `code.includes("<")` with no other checks is enough. And then you should still use `textContent` instead because it’s even simpler and less unusual.

Answer (score 1):

use `textConent` instead of `innerHTML`, so you won't have to worry about XSS

```html
<script>
     const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
     document.getElementById("txt-code").textContent = urlParams.get('code') ?? "";
     document.getElementById("txt-desc").textContent = urlParams.get('desc') ?? "";
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I want to know why my code is not very good about this? How the attacker bypass it?

Comment: they can use other html elements like imgs, textbox and many other, where the use attacker can post bad code which is hard to detect and removed.

Comment: They can not use because I also filter "<" and ">"